# Weird Grub Screen pops up after power outage

Tags: grub2, 19.10, grub-efi

My power went out this morning and now occasionally I get a grub prompt that shows up and not the grub select screen. I type exit from this screen and it goes to Grub, but then it won't boot into Windows until after another reboot. It boots into Ubuntu fine though. Why am I getting this screen and how do I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Boot in a live session

Plug in the live USB and boot into a live session.

Step 2: Install Boot Repair

Once you are in the live session, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to open  `terminal`. use the following commands to install Boot Repair:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt update
sudo apt install boot-repair
```

Step 3: Once you installed Boot Repair, run it from the `terminal` using the following command:

```
boot-repair &
```

Step 4: Click on Recommended repair option in the Boot Repair
[image: step 1]

Step 5: Afterwards, you will be provided with some commands to use in the command line. Copy the commands one by one in `terminal`. If you are getting any prompts, select `yes`

Step 6: Once the process finishes, shut down your computer, remove the USB and boot again.

Comment: Thanks i'll give that a shot.

Comment: That worked. I had found that myself on the internet before I asked here but one of the commands it has you use doesn't work. It references something like grub*-common instead of grub-common. Also it added a bunch of extra entries to my boot menu now but it does work.